# Filter entities by string containing in field of type array Realm DB React Native

Tags: react-native, realm

I have an array of realm entities of type:

```
{
name: string,
id: string,
labels: string[],
}
```

I need to filter these entities by keys containing in field array labels.

```
entities.filtered(`labels CONTAINS $0, ${key}`)
```

does not work

Comment: Realm has some pretty good docs and its always best practice to check them before posting questions. I found this [Query and Filter Results](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/crud/read/#query-for-an-object-type-and-filter-results) and a tip **To filter a query based on a property of an embedded object or a related object, use dot-notation**. Then more info on related objects (which is what you have) [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/model-data/relationships-and-embedded-objects/#std-label-react-native-relationships). Does that help?

Comment: I did read the docs, but in my case it is not and embedded object but simple array of strings inside a field not an object with its own schema

Comment: Correct, you could easily make those strings embedded objects as that's how they would behave in this use case anyway which then make a query very simple.